# Gui becomes less responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, async-await

First of all thanks for such a great community. I've learned a lot from your questions and answers here. This is my first question on S.O., so please be gentle :)

Ok, but first things first:

-1st code version:

```
private async void buttonWebScrap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickLink("/ptk/sun/core/cookie/CookiesHandler.accept");

    await Task.Delay(750);

    if (_backgroundTaskRunning || !ClickLink("msisdn-change")) return;

    _backgroundTaskRunning = true;
    await LongTaskAsync();
}

private async Task LongTaskAsync()
{
    const string previous = "msisdn-pool-prev";
    const string next = "msisdn-pool-next";

    var tempNumbers = new List<object>();
    
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(750);

        var document = webBrowser.DocumentText;
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(document);

        var numbers = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@id, 'msisdn')]");

        tempNumbers.AddRange(from number in numbers
                             where number.Id != previous && number.Id != next
                             select number.InnerText.RemoveEnters().RemoveSpaces().ReplaceSpecificChars());
        tempNumbers.Add("-------------------------");

        if (tempNumbers.Count >= 24)
        {
            listBoxNumbers.Items.AddRange(tempNumbers.ToArray());
            tempNumbers.Clear();
        }
        
        if (ClickLink(next) == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
} 

private bool ClickLink(string linkId)
{
    if (webBrowser.Document != null)
    {
        var elementById = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById(linkId);

        if (elementById != null)
        {
            elementById.InvokeMember("click");
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (webBrowser.Document.Window != null)
        {
            webBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 480);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

-2nd code version:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    _webBrowserDocuments = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    _progress = new Progress<string>();
    _progress.ProgressChanged += (o, s) => _objects.Add(s);

    _objects = new BindingList<string>();
    listBoxNumbers.DataSource = _objects;
}

private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserEmulation.Delete();
}

private async void buttonWebScrap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await WebBrowserClickLinkAsync("/ptk/sun/core/cookie/CookiesHandler.accept");

    if (_backgroundTaskRunning || !(await WebBrowserClickLinkAsync("msisdn-change"))) return;

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await WebBrowserDocumentDownloadAsync(cts);
    await DocumentParseAsync(_progress, cts);

    _backgroundTaskRunning = true;
}

private async Task DocumentParseAsync(IProgress<string> progress, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string tempDocument;
                if (_webBrowserDocuments.TryDequeue(out tempDocument))
                {
                    var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(tempDocument);

                    var numbers = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@id, 'msisdn')]");

                    foreach (var number in numbers.Where(number => number.Id != Previous && number.Id != Next).
                                                   Select(x => x.InnerText.RemoveEnters().RemoveSpaces().ReplaceSpecificChars()))
                    {
                        progress.Report(number);
                    }

                    progress.Report("-------------------------");
                }

                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, cts.Token);
}

private async Task WebBrowserDocumentDownloadAsync(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                _webBrowserDocuments.Enqueue(webBrowser.DocumentText);

                if (await WebBrowserClickLinkAsync(Next)) continue;
                cts.Cancel();
                break;
            }
        }, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
}

private async Task<bool> WebBrowserClickLinkAsync(string linkId)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (webBrowser.Document != null)
            {
                var elementById = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById(linkId);

                if (elementById != null)
                {
                    elementById.InvokeMember("click");
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (webBrowser.Document.Window != null)
                {
                    webBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 480);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
}
```

On the beggining everything is working just fine, but after webscraping about 500 of numbers, the "GUI" is a little bit sluggish. I don't know if it is with my "bad" understanding of async/await pattern, or something else. I thought that the second version will be better for this task - but it's still sluggish :/. Can someone help me with this?

Why I'm using webbrowser control instead of webclient? I know it will be a lot easier, but the site from which I'm webscraping is made with (as I see it) Java (jsessionId) + ajax, and there aren't "proper" links.

If you need some more details, just write ;)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

- second version is using Methods which are returning Task (or Task) to simplify the await with current SynchronizationContext from MainForm (only two of those)
- first version was the first approach of using await/async (as you can see the LongTaskAsync() method is async with await Task.Delay())
- this is a finished code (without some thinks like getting SynchronizationContext, setting ListBox.DataSource to BindList, etc.) with only 3 controls on winform - webbrowser, listbox and button ;)

Comment: How many items are you returning total?

Comment: Could you show us specifically what you changed rather than having us find the minor differences in code we're unfamiliar with? Your question would be a lot clearer.

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of small incremental UI updates.  Perhaps rather than updating the UI ever iteration of the loop you should report progress every 10, 50, or 100 iterations, based on what seems about right for your data.  If it's particularly variable don't update the UI on progress based on iterations, but just update some internal non-UI state and then update the UI through a `Timer` several times a second.

Answer (score 3):

The slowdown is likely due to adding your values to your user interface.

During your looping, you're adding the items to a list box:

```
    if (tempNumbers.Count >= 24)
    {
        listBoxNumbers.Items.AddRange(tempNumbers.ToArray());
        tempNumbers.Clear();
    }
```

As you get more and more results, the list box display will actually become a bottleneck, and cause things to slow down.  Since the list box must always be updated on the UI thread, this will cause your UI to get less responsive over time.

Your second option will likely be even worse, as you add items to a `BindingList<T>` one item at a time in the second option, and each addition will cause a refresh of the UI.

This could be mitigated by using a ListView with [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx) set to true, as this prevents the addition of new items from forcing a refresh on the screen.

Comment: Ok, I will try using ListView with VirtualMode turned on with the first code version.
What will be the best way of doing this? Change to WPF from WinForms? Or maybe something else? Do you have any more advice?

Comment: @dev4s WPF makes the virtualization easier, but the same issue will occur.  If you don't need to display the values, don't - try without adding the values to the UI until the very end, is that faster?

Comment: I need to see those values. I can also save them, and after that show them, but I must think of Users which will use this app in the future. How about database approach? Saving values to database and retrieve them after couple of seconds?

Comment: @dev4s Or just stick them in a collection, and pull from the collection on regular intervals... Just realize that they'll need to be virtualized if there are a lot of them, or it'll get progressively slower every update.